# Programmatic Auto Layout Constraints to Edges of Superview

Tags: swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have done quite a bit of auto layout in Xcode's storyboard editor, but I rarely ever do anything in code. In one particular instance, I need to create the programmatic equivalent to these constraints:

[image]

These constraints are added to `textView` and the superview is another view called `commentBox`. I've tried this so far, but the code feels redundant and results in an auto layout error of conflicting constraints:

```
//Trailing
textView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.commentBox, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 15))
//Leading
textView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.commentBox, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 15))
//Bottom
textView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.commentBox, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
//Top
textView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.commentBox, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did you turn off ```textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false```?

Comment: What conflicting constraints are you getting? One note: for **trailing** and **bottom** constraints, you want the `constant` value to be negative. That is, you want the `trailing` edge of the subview to be `15-pts` *to the left* of the `trailing` edge of the superview... so you want to use `-15` (and, as would be logical, `-10` for the `bottom` constraint).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
commentBox.addSubview(textView)

textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: commentBox.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: commentBox.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: commentBox.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: commentBox.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
```