# Vonage Video Position

Tags: ios, swift, video, tokbox

I am working on implementing the Vonage video API on IOS devices. I would like to know if there is a way to have my publisher view inside of a container view. I currently have my video views hard coded so the position of these views look different on different devices. I am hoping to utilize auto layout but I am not sure how the publisher view will react with storyboard. Please let me know if there is a way I can combine the publisher view with storyboard and how to go about implementing this. Here is a snippet of the code I currently have:

guard let publisher = OTPublisher(delegate: self, settings: settings) else {
return
}

```
     if ((session.capabilities?.canPublish) != nil) {
         // The client can publish.
         print("The client can publish.")
         guard let publisherView = publisher.view else {
             return
         }
         //added session.publish line
         session.publish(publisher, error: &error)
        let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        publisherView.frame = CGRect(x: screenBounds.width - 400, y: screenBounds.height - 850, width: 375, height: 350)
        publisherView.layer.borderWidth = 5
        publisherView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
      
        view.addSubview(publisherView)
```

Comment: Hi! the publisher view is a UIView. So you can add it as a subview of the container view, that you set up in the storyboard, then constraint the publisher view to all edges of the superview. Here is an example of that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54566584/9824067

Make sure to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on the publisher view to false.